# Debian on MacBook Pro 11,4 (15" Retina) - TouchPad and WiFi

Tags: debian, wifi, macintosh, touchpad, multi-touch

Thanks for reading this.

I have a mid 2015 MacBook Pro, 15" Retina, the 11,4 model. I installed Debian Jessie, running kernel 3.16, on an external hard-drive and can boot into it. I only have two problems:

I can use the mouse fine to point and click but I can't do anything that requires multitouch. For example, I can't scroll or right-click using the force touch trackpad. The Debian website says all the new trackpads should be supported so I am lost as to what to do. The system settings pane has only two options under Mouse/Trackpad which are not helpful.

My other problem is that I cannot get the internal WiFi thing to work. I got the proper driver and installed it (brcmfmac) but it says I need kernel 3.17 for it to work; when I check the available upgrades using `apt-get cache search linux-image` they are all 3.16. I am new to Linux so I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your multi-touch question off-hand. (My Macbook Pro 13" touchpad works fine on Debian 8, but it's a 2009 model.)

Regarding your second question — and ideally you should ask one question at a time on a Q&A site such as this one — the easiest way to install a newer kernel is to use [Jessie backports](https://backports.debian.org/).

First you need to add Jessie backports to your repositories, if it's not already there:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as root), then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

will install the current default backported kernel (4.6 as of this writing).

Enabling backports is safe: newer packages are not picked up automatically from backports, you need to explicitly select them using `-t jessie-backports` as above.

Answer (score 0):

To get the wifi working you need to:

> [Install "broadcom-sta-dkms" with a backported kernel from Jessie.](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/11-1#WLAN_.2F_Wifi)

1) Upgrade your kernel version : The easy way is by following the steps described by Stephen Kitt's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306178/153195) to install the 4.6 kernel version:

> `echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list`
>
> `apt-get update`
>
> `apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64`

2) Install the `broadcom-sta-dkms` package (`non-free`) and load the  `wl` kernel modules:

Add `non-free` to your `sources.list` and install required package:

```
apt-get install build-essential dkms wireless-tools
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload conflicting modules:

```
 modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe wl
```

To get the touchpad working you need to install the [`mtrack`](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack/) driver :

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

Edit the `50-synaptics.conf` configuration file:

```
nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Scroll down to the `section "InputClass"`, edit it like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
   Identifier      "Touchpads"
   Driver          "mtrack"
EndSection
```